# UIScreen.mainScreen.scale on NSScreen

Tags: ios, macos, swift, cocoa, catextlayer

I have a problem with CATextLayer cleaning.
and with iOS the solution is:

```
textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen.scale
```

But I can't found "scale" property on cocoa NSScreen

Note: Answer with Object-C or Swift are OK.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`[[NSScreen mainScreen] backingScaleFactor]` will give you the scaling factor for main display

Comment: I don't have Macbook retina, so I can't test your answer, please help me test on retina. On Macbook no retina [[NSScreen mainScreen] backingScaleFactor] = 1.

Comment: This API returns 2 if its a retina display

Comment: You can put any Mac into HiDPI mode for testing: http://cocoamanifest.net/articles/2013/01/turn-on-hidpi-retina-mode-on-an-ordinary-mac.html

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure it's the same as on iOS but `NSScreen` has `backingScaleFactor`, which might do the trick.

Comment: I don't have Macbook retina, so I can't test your answer, please help me test on retina. On Macbook no retina [[NSScreen mainScreen] backingScaleFactor] = 1.

Answer (score 2):

swift 4.2:

```
(NSScreen.main?.backingScaleFactor)!
```